# Add right Bar Button to Navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, selector

As the updates are going on with swift versions, I'am not able to add right bar button to my navigation bar. This is what i'm trying:

```
class feedViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Post",  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton(_:)))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton

    }

func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject){

    print("hjxdbsdhjbv")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

No compile error but when i run the app i don't see any button there.. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: add `let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Post",  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton(_:))) 

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton` in viewDidLoad

Comment: Still the same error.. maybe there's another syntax :/

Comment: post your full code and what is your xcode version???

Comment: in which Xcode you are tried this

Comment: But where did you add this ... is it viewController class or NSObject class ...

Comment: Sorry for that, it's in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to move your method out the scope of the method you are creating the `UIBarButtonItem` in.

For example try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Post",  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton))  

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton
    }


    func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("hjxdbsdhjbv")
    }
}
```

instead of this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Post",  style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton))  

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton

        func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            print("hjxdbsdhjbv")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Still the same error. That was not a problem though we can define a function before calling it. :/

Comment: Can you provide more code to give context? The code I provided works for me.

Comment: It's important to note that the `didTapEditButton` is now _outside_ of the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: yeah.. i have updated the code in the question, i have no error but when i run the app , i don't see any button there..

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller? Is the navigation bar visible? How is your `feedViewController` presented?

Comment: yeah i have navigation controller.. first user login through parse when user logs in the next screen is feedViewController which is in TabBarController.
navigation bar does appear

Comment: It seems like your question has changed - your original issue referred to a compilation issue _"Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to Objective-C."_ Nesting a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` might not act quite how you expect it to - take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!